# compiling systemd with kdbus miraclecast

Tags: systemd

I am trying to compile systemd with the kdbus using the PKGBUILD of this following documentation.(https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues/61). I don't quite understand how this is done. I am running arch arm on the raspberry pi 3. I think my goal is enable the kdbus for the pi by compiling the kdbus through systemd. Can anyone clarify and help me out with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have debian stretch version, it will already have the required systemd version. Just check

> systemd --version

It will be 232 in stretch  which will work fine for miraclecast.

Comment: Or `sudo cat /etc/debian_version`